# My WPF app deployed using click once wont start

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have simple WPF app that I deployed using click once to shared folder on my computer so it can be installed via local network. When I click on install button , it prompts me to download/save setup file, and when I run it, it installs app to my computer. But, when I try to start it I get this screen

[image]

and then nothing happens. Any ideas...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dialog is checking for updates. My best guess is that you have an unhandled exception that occurs on application startup, which causes your app to crash.

For WPF, you will want to add handlers to both of these events:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException
```

I usually attach to them in my application class's `OnStartup` method. In the event handlers, I would then log the exception, so I can look at what is failing in production.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me to log exception message during the start of application so I'm now able to solve the problem.